# Geometric mean-algorithm without package

Tags: python-3.x, mean

I have a task to write a program which for a sequence number as a result give a geometric mean. I have to write this program without any package. 
The introduction of the program end, when users give a 0.
The program should report an error if the first number is 0 and if the user gives a negative number.

```py
def sequence():
    prod=1
    i=-1
    x=1
    n = int(input("Give a number: "))
    while True:
        if n == 0:
            break
        elif i==0:
            print("Error")
        else:
            prod=prod*n
            i=i+1
            result=prod**(1/i)
            print(" Średnia wartośc ciągu ", result)
            return i, suma
            sequence()
```

My program doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to post the solution, I'd rather point out several problems with the code. Figuring them out on your own will make you a better coder. There are several problems with your algorithm:

1. You'd better start with `i=0`
2. `elif i==0:` won't work as you expect it has to be an `if i==0:` under `if n==0:`, so that you exit the loop when you get `0` from the user and you print `Error` when it is the first iteration.
3. `n = int(input("Give a number: "))` has to be within the loop, so that it gets assigned on every iteration of your algorithm.
4. `return i, suma` should be outside the `while` loop.